# Condition for absorbing convex sets absorbing each other

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ absorbing convex sets, where $\mathbb{R}^n$ has its usual metric. Suppose

$d(A,B):=\max\{\sup_{a\in A} d(a,B),\sup_{b\in B} d(b,A)\}<\infty$.

> Does this suffice to say $A$ and $B$ absorb each other? Meaning that there are $r_1,r_2>0$ such that $A\subseteq r_1B$ and $B\subseteq r_2A$.

I think the answer is yes somehow. If $d(A,B)$ is finite these sets are "close" to each other. And since for every $a\in A$ there is $r_a$ with $a\in r_aB$, I think there should be one $r$ that works for all of them. But how can we determine this $r$?

Any hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In finite dimensions, an absorbing convex set $A$ contains a ball centered at $0$, which can be proved by a compactness argument (involving a convergent subsequence of unit vectors).

By convexity, $rA = A+(r-1)A$  (Minkowski sum) for any $r>1$. When $r$ is large enough, the set $(r-1)A$ contains a ball centered at $0$ with radius greater than $d(A,B)$. Hence $B\subset A+(r-1)A = rA$, which provides an affirmative answer to your question.

---

In infinite dimensional spaces the result is false. Consider the space $c_{00}$ of sequences with finitely many nonzero elements. Equip it with the $\ell^2$ norm. Let $$A=\{x\in \ell^2:\|x\|_2\le 1\},\quad B=\{x\in \ell^2:\|x\|_1 \le 1\}$$
Then $A$ is bounded and $B\subset A$, so $d_H(A,B)$ is finite. Both sets are absorbing in $c_{00}$. Yet, there is no $r$ such that $A\subset rB$, because of vectors like
$$
x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(e_1+\dots+e_n)
$$
which satisfy $\|x\|_2 = 1$ and $\|x\|_1=\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the delay. I ssupose it is false in infinite-dimensions but I'll thought about it.

Comment: Yes it's false: see the addition to the answer.